# Expression Engine 2: Low Alphabet not fully working

Tags: content-management-system, expressionengine

So I'm working on a site and they required alphabetical lists of their entries and I was pointed to Low Alphabet.. Very simple to install and found some *basic* examples to get it floating. I can sort and create a nav that dynamically generates based on the last name channel field.

However, on my EE2 installation the only thing it is doing now is dynamically creating a nav bar with a letter for each unique alphabet entry (in this case, Q and Z). But when I direct it to the 'list' page I've created it will not display only the pertinent entries. It displays all of them with no sorting.

Here's the principle code from the 'list' template in question:

```
<div class="videolist-wrap"> 
{exp:low_alphabet:entries channel="pcp_clergy" limit="12" paginate="bottom" alpha-filter="{segment_3}" orderby="clergy_last_name"}
{if count == "1"}<ul class="video-list">{/if}
<li class="utility">
<div class="video-holder">
<a href="#" class="video">
<img src="{clergy_preview_image}" alt="{title}" width="188" height="110"/>
</a>

<!--<a href="#" class="video">
<img src="{images}img15.jpg" alt="Image Description" width="188" height="110"/>
</a> -->
<strong class="title"><a href="#">{clergy_first_name} {clergy_last_name}</a></strong>
<p>{clergy_congregation}</p>
</div>
<ul>
{if '{clergy_endorsed}' != ""}
<li class="orange">Endorsed</li>
{if:else}
<li class="grey">Endorsed</li>
{/if}

{if '{clergy_recognized}' != ""}
<li class="orange">Recognized</li>
{if:else}
<li class="grey">Recognized</li>
{/if}
</ul>
</li>

{if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
{paginate}
{pagination_links}
<ul class="pagination">
{first_page}
<li><a href="{pagination_url}">First Page</a></li>
{/first_page}
{previous_page}
<li class="prev"><a href="{pagination_url}">Previous Page</a></li>
{/previous_page}
{page}
{if current_page}
<li class="active"><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
{/if}
{if !current_page}
<li><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
{/if}
{/page}
{next_page}
<li class="next"><a href="{pagination_url}">Next Page</a></li>
{/next_page}
{last_page}
<li class="last"><a href="{pagination_url}">Last Page</a></li>
{/last_page}
</ul>
{/pagination_links}
{/paginate} 
{/exp:low_alphabet:entries}
```

What exactly do I have wrong with my code in regards to the Low Alphabet plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was using a dash instead of an underscore for alpha_filter (I put alpha-filter). Simple fix!